# Java: [profileName=AD_Auth] Error fetching groups.javax.naming.AuthenticationException

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I have a software that is built in Java and review the logs that this software generates, I view this message: **"[profileName=AD_Auth] Error fetching groups.javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090421, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v23f0]"**, I think that is related to authentication on Active Directory and the user that we use in the software, but reviewing the user at AD, this has no change, the password is the same of the beginning of time and had the same authorizations, the user is not locked, etc. So, I don´t know what is the problem. Thanks

Comment: Use Wireshark, review our credentails, they must be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of the code, I can only take an educated guess. But I'd suggest setting the authentication type to "ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION" as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772247(VS.85).aspx